# MS Word 365 - Multiple footnote references same word

Tags: microsoft-word, office365, text-formatting, footnote, microsoft-word-365

I'm triyng to write an essay and I need to insert some footnotes. My issue is I can't figure out how to insert multiple footnotes on the same spot. I mean if I insert them one after another,say 3 for example, the notes number ABOVE the word look like this "123" which looks like "one hundred and twenty three". What I'd like to obtain is some sort of separator, an example output would be the numbers printed ABOVE to look like this "1,2,3".

Is this stuff possible? And how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this does not happen often in your document, the simplest thing to do is to insert commas (",") manually between the footnote numbers, then format them using the style `Footnote Reference` (that's the name in the English-language version of Word, anyway).

I say "simplest" with caution because it may not be at all obvious how to do that. But e.g.

- Select the comma
- In the Ribbon, navigate to the *Home* tab, *Styles* group
- Click the *Dialog Launcher* icon at the bottom right of the group. That displays a task pane showing the styles.
- If you don't see the `Footnote Reference` style in there, click the *Options* button and select `All styles` under *Select styles to show*.
- Find and select the Footnote Reference style and apply it to the selection.

You may find it easier to insert *one* comma formatted that way and save it as an autotext or autocorrect for re-use.

If it is something you need a lot, and/or you also need to replace footnote references such as 34,35,36,37 by 34-37, then you will need to decide what *rules* to apply, and you will need some VBA or equivalent code to apply them. For the *rules*, for example, how many contiguous footnote markers before you use a hyphen (or perhaps a dash) so you have 34-37 rather than 34,35,36,37? What if there are other references such as endnotes in the middle?

Comment: Thank you. Your simpliest way did the job. I didn't relly understand your other part of the answer since I don't know how to write such rules. Could you link me a guide? I'm interested in learning this skill and I don't know where to look

Comment: @LucaFederzoni what I'm really saying is that if you need to write something in VBA or want to ask someone to write it for you (I wouldn't try that on this site!), you need to be very clear how you want the referencing to look. How simple it would be to turn that into a piece of VBA depends on how complicated those rules are and how easy you find programming in general, among other things.

Comment: Ok, I understood. Thanks for your advice. Since I have to do so little of this feature I'll stick with the style Plan.